# Why is the mass of the wizard's kit less than the sum of its parts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

I am reading PZO1123 Ultimate Equipment and note the following:

The mass of the wizard's kit is 21 lbs. It includes a backpack (2 lbs), a bedroll (5 lbs), torches (10 × 1 lb each), trail rations (5 × 1 lb each), and some other things... but that's already 22 lbs! Why is it so? I assume the starting kits are nonmagical.

Comment: Welcome to this stack! Take the [tour]. I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76884/8610), but I've not marked it as such yet. If you think that it's not, please edit this question to make clear its differences from the linked question. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Yes it is. I searched on the topic earlier but clearly failed my Perception check.

Answer (score 2):

In many systems (as well as non-tabletop games like MMOs) the "weight" of items is a measure of how cumbersome they are, not just weight. Things that make it easier to handle the items might reduce this value.

For example, in Fantasy Flight Games' Star Wars RPG system, items like backpacks and utility belts allow for a larger encumbrance value to be stored inside them than they would total otherwise. (e.g. storing 5 encumbrance of items but only costing 3 points)

In these cases, you could consider this the effect of the items being neatly and compactly stored, making them easier to manage. It would be a lot easier to handle a backpack stuffed with all the items you listed than it would to try and wrangle all of those items loose in your arms.